# Linux kernel: get function address for kernel driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it possible in a linux kernel module to get the pointer of a function exported by another kernel module (something like `cat /proc/kallsyms`) but with api calls. Also if it would be possbile to load the intended module into memory if it doesn't exist.
Basically what i am trying to do is to introduce a soft dependency between 2 modules. so i can execute one with or without the other.

Comment: There used to be a way to do this via module_request(), inter_module_get(), and inter_module_get_request().  This functionality may have been removed a long time ago.  +1 as I'd be very interested in what others have to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Using following Linux Kernel APIs,

1. Using `find_symbol` API, you can search for desired symbol exists or not
2. If it fails to find symbol, then you can try to load desired module which exports symbol which you intended to use using APIs called `find_module` and `request_module`. Here is sample code for these APIs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23310258/1075324)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:  kallsyms_lookup_name(const char *name)
Just include linux/kallsyms.h